# Fix header formatting on resume

Tags: cv, header

I want to reformat the header of my resume such that my email, github and phone number are stacked on top of one another on the right, and not overlapping.

[image: header]

File `cv.tex`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{style} % Use US Letter paper, change to a4paper for A4 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\ci#1{\textcircled{\resizebox{.5em}{!}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\lastupdated % Print the Last Updated text at the top right
\namesection{{Lolita}}{Nazarov}{
\href{mailto:lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}{\ci{\faEnvelope}} {\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont \href{mailto:lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}{lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}}}

{
\href{https://github.com/lolitanaz314}{\ci{\faGithub}} {\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont \href{https://github.com/lolitanaz314}{github.com/lolitanaz314}}
}

{
\ci{\faPhone}  {\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont 631-456-1964} 
}

\input{page1.tex}

\end{document}
```

`Style.cls` class:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CLASS OPTIONS AND REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\ProvidesClass{style}[2014/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.75cm]{geometry} % Specifies horizontal and vertical page margins
\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for links
\usepackage{enumitem} % for setting list indent

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLORS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for custom colors

\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} % The primary document color for content text
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{42b9f4} % The color of the large sections
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333} % The color of subsections and places worked/studied
\definecolor{subsubheadings}{HTML}{6A6A6A} % The color of the large sections
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} % The color used for the Last Updated text at the top right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fontspec} % Required for specifying custom fonts in XeLaTeX

\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Reg,ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig} % The primary font for content text; defines bold, italic and bold-italic as well

\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight} % The font used where \sfffamily is called

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN HEADING COMMAND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\namesection}[8]{ % Defines the command for the main heading
\color{headings}
% name
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.47\textwidth}
\raggedright{ % Center the name
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\color{black}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
} %\\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
\end{minipage}
% phone / email
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.22\textwidth}
\vspace{-28 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#3 
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#4
\end{minipage}
% phone / email
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.20\textwidth}
\vspace{-30 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#5
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#6
% Contact information font
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.1\textwidth}
\vspace{-27 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#7
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#8
% Contact information font
\end{minipage}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{subsubheadings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE STYLING AND SPACING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % Required for customizing section/subsection/etc titles
\usepackage{textcase}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt} % Removes the spacing around the main section titles
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt} % Removes the spacing around the subsections
\newcommand{\sectionspace}{\vspace{8pt}} % Defines a command to add a set amount of space after sections and subsections

\titleformat{\section}{ % Customize the large section titles
\color{headings}\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\fontsize{16pt}{24pt}\selectfont \raggedright \bfseries \lowercase}{}{0em}{} % chandan removed \uppercase

\titleformat{\subsection}{ % Customize the subsections and places worked/studied titles
\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries \lowercase}{}{0em}{} % removed \uppercase

\newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{ % Used for creating subsections where a description is required on the same line
\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\lowercase {#1} \normalfont} % removed \uppercase

\newcommand{\descript}[1]{ % Used for describing the subsection either on the same line or underneath
\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont\lowercase {#1 \\} \normalfont}

\newcommand{\location}[1]{ % Used for specifying a duration and/or location under a subsection
\color{subsubheadings}\raggedright\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont\lowercase {#1\\} \normalfont}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE STYLING AND SPACING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{tightitemize} % Defines the tightitemize environment which modifies the itemize environment to be more compact
{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.2in]\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt }
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post *full* compilable code?

Comment: @Bernard I edited the code - thank you!

Comment: Without having `style.cls`, it's impossible to guess what can be done.

Comment: @Bernard Added style.cls - I took it off of an existing template.

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 1):

Well, this template is not the very best and if possible do not use it.

Why you will see in the following ...

The command `\namesection` is defined to have 8 parameters like

```
\namesection{firstname-1}{lastname-2}{mailsymbol-3}{mail-4}{githubsymbol-5}{github-6}{phonesymbol-7}{phone-8}
```

Therefore you have to use the following command in your cv:

```
    \namesection{Lolita}{Nazarov}% parameter 1 and 2
      {\href{mailto:lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}{\ci{\faEnvelope}}}% 3
      {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont \href{mailto:lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}{lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}}%4
      {\href{https://github.com/lolitanaz314}{\ci{\faGithub}}} %5
      {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont \href{https://github.com/lolitanaz314}{github.com/lolitanaz314}}%6
      {\ci{\faPhone}}%7  
      {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont 631-456-1964} %8
```

Please see that I reduced the fontsize to get the infos printed in the available place.

To get the mail, github and phone info on one line you have to redefine command `\namesection` in your preamble like this (see changed codes, i.e. values marked with `<=====`):

```
\renewcommand{\namesection}[8]{ % Defines the command for the main heading
\color{headings}
% name
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.47\textwidth}
\raggedright{ % Center the name
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\color{black}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
} %\\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
\end{minipage}
% phone / email
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.22\textwidth}
\vspace{-27 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space <==========
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#3 
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#4
\end{minipage}
% phone / email
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.18\textwidth} % 20 <======================
\vspace{-30 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space <==========
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#5
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#6
% Contact information font
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.1\textwidth}
\vspace{-30 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space <==========
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#7
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#8
% Contact information font
\end{minipage}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{subsubheadings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}
```

Depending on your real used datas you have to play with all marked values to get a proper printed header of your CV! It would be better in this case to use an table with variable length for the columns.

So with the following MWE (no changes are needed in the class file!):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{style} % Use US Letter paper, change to a4paper for A4 

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{hyperref} % <=============================================== called last!!

\def\ci#1{\textcircled{\resizebox{.5em}{!}{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\namesection}[8]{ % Defines the command for the main heading
\color{headings}
% name
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.47\textwidth}
\raggedright{ % Center the name
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\color{black}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
} %\\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
\end{minipage}
% phone / email
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.22\textwidth}
\vspace{-27 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space <==========
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#3 
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#4
\end{minipage}
% phone / email
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.18\textwidth} % 20 <======================
\vspace{-30 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space <==========
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#5
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#6
% Contact information font
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][.8cm][t]{.1\textwidth}
\vspace{-30 pt} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space <==========
%\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{subsubheadings} % Use the headings color
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\fontsize{22}{18}\selectfont 
#7
\vspace{6 pt}
\\
#8
% Contact information font
\end{minipage}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{subsubheadings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\lastupdated % Print the Last Updated text at the top right
%\namesection{firstname-1}{lastname-2}{mailsymbol-3}{mail-4}{githubsymbol-5}{github-6}{phonesymbol-7}{phone-8}
\namesection{Lolita}{Nazarov}%1 and 2
  {\href{mailto:lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}{\ci{\faEnvelope}}}% 3
  {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont \href{mailto:lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}{lolita.nazarov@stonybrook.edu}}%4
  {\href{https://github.com/lolitanaz314}{\ci{\faGithub}}} %5
  {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont \href{https://github.com/lolitanaz314}{github.com/lolitanaz314}}%6
  {\ci{\faPhone}}%7  
  {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont 631-456-1964} %8

\input{page1.tex}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting header]

Comment: Thank you so so much!! @Mensch